# Field not being read as a character string

Tags: sas

**Solved. See footnote.**

```
            /*check regex*/
            go = 1; 
            i = 1; 
            do while (go = 1);
                set braw.regex point = i;
                    if (upcase(fname) = upcase("&var.")) then do;

                        put format1 " one"; /*format1 is a field of braw.regex, properties says character length 30*/
                        if format1 = '/\d{8}/' then put 'hello world one'; else put 'good bye world one';
                        %check1(&data, format1, &var) 


                    end;
                    else i = i+1;  

            end;

      /*check1 passes regex, string, true false to check_format*/
%macro check_format(regex, string, truefalse);

    pattern = prxparse(&regex.);
    truefalse = prxmatch(pattern, &string); 
    put &regex " " &string " " &truefalse "post";
%mend;
```

So sorry about the lack of indentation - stackover flow seems to be being buggy or something.

This outputs

```
 /\d{8}/ one
good bye world one
```

apparently format isn't a string. So it then fails the prxparse, as it's looking for a string input. 
Any idea of what I do?

I was thinking I could use a macro variable to put quotes around it, perhaps using:

```
call symput('mymacrovar', format1);
%let mymacrovar = "&mymacrovar";
```

but that symput does nothing.

**Solved:**
It was being read as a string. On the CSV file that the regex dataset was being read from, there were additional spaces between the commas, making the string ' /\d{8}/' which prxparse doesn't like.

Comment: You can (and should) put your solution in as a solution and mark it correct :)

Comment: And using <pre> rather than <code> will sort the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *was* being read as a string. On the CSV file that the regex dataset was being read from, there were additional spaces between the commas, making the string '_/\d{8}/' (underscore denoting a space) which prxparse doesn't like.